# Workspace period has ended recover data drive

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail, google-workspace

Your 14-day trial of Google Workspace has ended.

Workspace period has ended, at the end of the period I have lost access to email and my Google Drive, how could I recover only the data from the Drive and emails. I don't want to continue using the service, just recover the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that the services have been suspended since your 14-day trial ended. From the looks of it, you have two options to move forward to gain access to your data and have it exported.

1. [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) and ask if they can extend your trial period so that you can access your account and its data. You may also seek their assistance to see how you can get your data out of the account.
2. Set up a payment method for your account to reactivate your services, and from there, access your account to export your data, and then delete the Google Workspace account once you're finished so that you won't be billed.

Nothing can be accessed if the account is inactive; it's best to do one of those options first and then use something like [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) to export your data.

I hope this information helps!